# animated line in GUI - matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, animation, simulation

Hi I'm trying to create a gui for a simulation, it has two axes handles, one of them changes interactively within iteration in the loop
I wish to us `animatedline` and `drawnow` commands to update it. however cannot connect it with the handles I created:

```
f=figure('Visible','on','Position',[2800,100, 1000,800]);
ha1 = axes('Units','pixels','Position',[50,50,400,320]);
ha2 = axes('Units','pixels','Position',[550,50,400,320]);
h=animatedline;
```

and inside the loop I want to update:

```
   axes(ha1)
   addpoints(t,X);
   draw now
```

so my problem is to connect `ha1` with `h`, i.e, to show the animated line in the axes I defined above

;

Comment: In the code excerpt you wrote `addpoints(t,X);`, notice that the first parameter of [addpoints](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpoints.html) shall be the `handle` of the `animatedline` (in you case, `h`); therefore, if `t` and `X` are the _x_ and _y_ coordinates of the points you want to add, your statement should be `addpoints(h,t,X);`

Comment: does not solve the problem